# Connect Wall - Find the common word: Senior, Station, U.S., Request

Tags: word, knowledge, connect-wall

Connect Wall (my first one):

```
Senior      Station     U.S.        Request
Travel      Boy         Benefit     Club
Group       Card        Private     Zone
Rights      Jam         Open        Family
```

1. Find 4 categories with 4 words in each one.
2. Find the common word for the categories (with the same pattern).

---

Hint for the pattern that this wall follows:

> In each group the category name is a word that either precedes or follows the words in the group to make up a new known word or phrase.

Comment: edited title: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1437/can-we-please-edit-very-hard-difficult-and-easy-out-of-titles

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Numbers and user-IDs in the title are also unhelpful. I've edited to a more descriptive title for now, but would encourage the OP to re-edit to an even better title. Perhaps a vague hint towards the form of the solution? E.g. if Brandon and I are correct about the overall topic, you could make the title something like "Connect Wall: go, go, go!"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I finally figured it out:

> **CITIZEN**: Senior, U.S, Private, Rights (from Yodaswag)
>  **SPACE**: Station, Travel, Jam, Open (*space* station, *space* travel, *Space* Jam, open *space*)
>  **FRIEND**: Zone, Boy, Request, Family (*friend* zone, boy*friend*, *friend* request, family *friend*)
>  **MEMBER**: Benefit, Card, Club, Group (*member* benefit, card *member*, club *member*, group *member*)
>
>  **SHIP**: Citizen*ship*, space*ship*, friend*ship*, member*ship*

Comment: Yes, all correct!

Answer (score 7):

Ok, so I think I figured 1 of the 4 categories.

the category for the words:

> Senior, U.S, Private and Rights is Citizen.

explanation:

> Senior citizen, U.S. citizen, Private Citizen, and Citizen Rights.

also I think the words:

> Travel, Card and station are in the same category.

Comment: First category is right!

Answer (score 4):

I think the overall common theme is

> TRAVEL.

First group:

> SENIOR, GROUP, FAMILY, ??? - they can all be types of TICKET.

Second group:

> JAM, PRIVATE?, ZONE?, ??? - these words all go together with TRAFFIC.

Third group:

> STATION, OPEN?, ???, ??? - these words all go together with BUS.

Fourth group:

> U.S., ZONE?, OPEN?, ??? - these words all go together with BORDER.

I'm not sure about all of the words, but I think I'm on the right track here ...

Comment: I think the second word of your second group is incorrect and should possibly go with the first group.

Comment: Nice try, but this is not correct

Answer (score 3):

**1.**

> **CITIZEN** Senior *Citizen*, *Citizen*'s Rights, Private *Citizen*, US *Citizen* (@Yodaswag)

**2.** ?

> **INSURANCE** Travel *Insurance*, *Insurance* Benefits, Group *Insurance*, *Insurance* Card

**3.**??

> **BUS** *Bus* Station, *Bus* Boy, *Bus* Zone, Family *Bus*

**4.**??

> **SESSION** Jam *Session*, Club *Session*, *Session* Request, Open *Session*

Common Theme????:

> Jeff Sessions, Former US Attorney General?!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess that the broad category is

> *VACATION*.

First Group:

> Open, Private, Club, Request. *Possible* category names: lodge, ticket, access.

Second Group:

> Senior, Group, Family, Travel. Category name: **Discount**

Third Group:

> Card, Rights, U.S., Boy. Category name: **Customs**?

Fourth Group:

> Travel, Station, Jam, Zone. Category name: **Transportation**?

Comment: The category names should be more obvious when you'll have the right words.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the first group as solved by @Yodaswag

> Senior, U.S, Private and Rights is **Citizen**.

After this, a second group I can think of

> Travel, Card, Open and Family is **Business**
> as in business travel, business card, open business and family business

From this I take a bigger leap and organize the remaining words as

> Request, Station, Group and Zone is **Military**
> Club, Benefit, Jam and Boy is **Family**

This four category can mean that the answer is

> **Law**, because citizen (civil rights), business, military and family are all fields of law

Comment: Your answer actually fits very well (maybe except for the last one..) but it is not what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is:

1.

> CITIZEN 
>  Senior, Rights, U.S., Private

2.

> PACKAGE 
> Family, Benefit, Club, Group

3.

> BUS 
> Boy, Station, Travel, Card

4.

> ??? 
> Jam, Open, Request, Zone